# Comparing Self Hosting: WCF vs HttpListener

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, signalr, httplistener

I've been looking into the possibility of using ASP.NET Web API and SignalR in a self-hosted application, and I noticed that the ASP.NET Web API self-hosted implementation uses WCF, and the SignalR self-hosted implementation uses `System.Net.HttpListener`. This makes it a little harder to come up with a combined self-hosting solution, but it does get me wondering why the different project teams would use different approaches.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach? Is there any particular reason why SignalR could not use WCF self-hosting, or Web API could not use HttpListener?

**EDIT**: I understand that Web API self-hosting provides a more complete stack than SignalR, my question is more about why you would choose a WCF implementation over System.Net.HttpListener when implementing your own self-hosting solution.

Comment: I've been looking around for comparisons of why I would choose `HttpListener` over WCF, or vice versa but still have not found a good comparison. Perhaps I'm not looking hard enough. In case anyone is interested, I have written a self-hosting solution for Web API and SignalR. It uses `HttpListener` for the simple fact that it seemed easier to make Web API support `HttpListener`, rather that make SignalR support WCF. I hope it is of use. https://github.com/jjeffery/WebAppHost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so we are on the same page, The WCF Self-host that Web API Self host uses, does use HttpListener under the covers.  However, I think I may have found a major downside to the WCF Self-host.

I have not confirmed this yet, but it seems that when you use Web API Self Host, the base address you provide is not translated directly into a HttpListener prefix.  It seems like WCF translates the base address and wildcards the host.

This means that the WCF self-host will respond to any host on the specified port.  This means that you cannot run a Web API Self hosted service side by side with IIS on the same port using a different host name.

This might be the reason that SignalR decided to scrap the WCF Self-Host and use HTTPListener directly.

Comment: You are right that WCF uses `HttpListener` under the covers -- it adds its own layer on top. I've been wondering what it adds over `HttpListener`. When you specify a URL in WCF self hosting, you seem to need to use 'localhost' in the URL and it means "listen on any port", which is a little strange to my way of thinking. Thanks for the response. Given that nobody else seems much interested in this question (or wants to tell me to use something else, like OWIN, hostable web core, etc), I'll choose your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Web API self host provides entire HTTP stack so it's much much richer than System.Net.HttpListener.

SignalR uses that to purely open a communication window for its own purposes. 
So yeah for now, you need to run them in parallel on different ports.

In the future, with OWIN, you will have everything under one roof.

---

EDIT: there was actually an issue similar to yours raised on SignalR github, and the answer was pretty much what I just said - https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/277

Comment: Thanks for your answer Filip, and I agree with your comment about Web API having a more complete stack, but this is not necessarily to do with it being written using WCF. My question was more about the advantages/disadvantages of the System.Net.HttpListener approach to Self-Hosting vs the WCF approach. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: The Web API Self host is based on WCF self host which in turn is based on HttpListener, so it's only "richer" due to the layering of additional features on top of HTTPListener.

Answer (score 2):

While you can use the WCF stack to host the services yourself, you may want to consider the "IIS 7.0 Hostable Web Core". It has the benefit of running IIS in your user process. Using this approach, you can have several applications running on the same port, irrespective of the technologies.

If you are interested, you can look at:

1. [Host your own Web Server in your application using IIS 7.0 Hostable Web Core](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/hostyourownwebserverusingiis7.aspx)
2. [Creating Hosted Web Core Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689327%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

This all assumes you are running Vista or later...

Comment: Thanks Werner, I am aware of hostable web core, and it might be useful in some cases. In my case I need to support Windows XP still, so it's not going to help this time. I'm also not sure if hostable web core works on desktop machines that have not had IIS installed.

Comment: It was unclear which OS you were using. You may want to try the tcp port sharing service, which may allow you to host two apps in two processes on the same port. Used it successfully in Windows 2003 before and its supported in Windows XP, even though I never used it on that platform.

Comment: Thanks Werner, just to confirm that I am not so much asking how to combine SignalR and Web API, rather I am asking why you would choose to use `HttpListener` over WCF or vice versa.